# Is it safe for Task.Run() to access Method scope variables?

Tags: c#, scope

Is the following guaranteed to print "Success," or is it possible garbage collection can eat the "dummyValue" object since TaskTest() ends long before the task it returns can finish?

```
public class DummyValueClass
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public DummyValueClass(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class ScopeTest
{
    public Task<string> TaskTest()
    {
        var dummyValue = new DummyValueClass("Success");

        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            return dummyValue?.Value;
        });
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Beginning Test");
        var scopeTester = new ScopeTest();
        var task = scopeTester.TaskTest();
        Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Arguably safer, from a "concurrent access to resources" point of view, I dare say

Comment: It is guaranteed to print `Success`.  The compiler is smart enough to know that `dummyValue` is still in scope and not to garbage collect it.  [See this first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634566/how-does-a-lambda-expression-shares-a-local-variable) for more info.

Comment: @Jonesopolis Sweet. Would you like to answer this question so I can mark it?

Comment: There is no difference to object lifetimes or variable scopes between a Task lambda and any other lambda (lambda expressions are different). While tasks *may* run in different threads, that is not a concern here and the value is immutable. There are some guarantees about task execution and *thread visibility*, although it is still subject to general threading rules when scheduled on threads, such as the default scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a *closure*.

```
var dummyValue = new DummyValueClass("Success");

return Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    return dummyValue?.Value;
});
```

In short the compiler creates a *compiler generate class* and captures `dummyValue` as an *instance member*.

Example of sanitized emitted code. You can view all the gory details [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEB0AVAFgJwKYEMATASwDsBzAblgWQgFZq4BmZMRAYUQG9ZF/EfASFbhEAEQCuAW2kBPAGr4ANpNwdl+AM5bYvGAOSiISJatw9E5XABdKiAA7ZiAN3w2LW2/YC+sIfwiEjLyZmoa2loAFChIbuYAlAE8yYZhFgC8iPFqTIZ+MAX+MDSi7ADKAMYA9g646LhaNnrJQSAAbAA8sQB8yO0NTVFJBgL6hoZu2IiEIYoqaohZpLgA7sGy8+YROlEAROWSlZWNWnsJTKnCAOz9qABKkqRRw0s9V/zjE99YeESo5WUuFwDiiJngEIuHwmIFus026QA/Kh0nlvogfFDRvwCkVsUZkAAWRAAWVeX3R6JQAE59gAhXDkMikMjkRCDGznNHfKaILQ1Ooc3DTZZrRBVWr1Ro2Ybcia8mzaADWSz5AqlTWFqA6HNl0JpUUVWiVD0akmUNix+VgPiAA===)

```
public class ScopeTest
{
   [CompilerGenerated]
   private sealed class GeneratedClass
   {
      public DummyValueClass dummyValue;

      internal string InternalTaskTest()
      {
         Thread.Sleep(10000);
         DummyValueClass dummyValueClass = dummyValue;
         if (dummyValueClass == null)
         {
            return null;
         }
         return dummyValueClass.Value;
      }
   }

   public Task<string> TaskTest()
   {
      GeneratedClass generatedClass = new GeneratedClass();
      generatedClass.dummyValue = new DummyValueClass("Success");
      return Task.Run(new Func<string>(generatedClass.InternalTaskTest));
   }
}
```

The *task* now has a *method pointer* to the generated method, which in turn roots the `GeneratedClass` which has a reference to your `DummyValueClass`. The result being that the *Garbage Collector* knows your *reference* is still alive.

Comment: Accepted answer for being the most in-depth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is guaranteed to print "Success". Because when a lambda captures value outside from its scope, the compiler will generate an object which "captures" the variables acquired from outside its scope. So it will not be garbage collected